# Using this.id with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I am passing a DOM object after an onclick event occurs and I need to know the id of the element I've passed from the html. I've read about the `this.id` that exists in JavaScript but I cannot seem to utilize it correctly.

Here is my code in the function:

```
function clickFunction() {
    $(".tictactoe").on('click', function() {

        $(this).text("X");
        if (this.id == "upleft") {
            $('#upright').text("yes");
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#playagain').hide();
    $('.tictactoe').on("click");

    clickFunction();

});
```

So I thought that my quick test, if successful, would present the word yes in the grid of a tic tac to bar in the upper right corner when I clicked the position on the left.

Perhaps there is something wrong with my comparison?

```
this.id == "upright"
```

The X's show up, indicating the rest of the code works, so it must be the comparison. Let me know your thoughts.

Comment: use `console.log(this.id)` to see what the actual value is, and be aware of any whitespace.

Comment: @adeneo I tried this and then looked for it in the console dev tool on chrome, but it did not show up there, even after I made the click. Thoughts?

Comment: You either did'nt include jQuery, don't have an element with the class `.tictactoe`, or the element with the class `.tictactoe` does not have an ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the clickFunction in the click handler. Then remove the unnecessary click handler in the function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#playagain').hide();
    $('.tictactoe td').on("click", clickFunction);    //Added td click handler
});

function clickFunction()
{
    $(this).text("X");
    if(this.id == "upleft")
    {
        $('#upright').text("yes");
    }
}
```

Comment: This did not work for some reason... it still just prints the x. I verfied that the id's are upleft and upright and have a # when appropriate as in your answer but it still did not work

Comment: You want to select the "box" you are clicking. However you are placing a click handler on the the whole tictactoe board.  How is your html set up?

Comment: The grid for the tic tac toe is a table with appropriate borders. Each `td` of the table has an id of its location e.g upleft upright etc and a class of tictactoe. I see your point about placing a single event listener on the entire grid. How can I change my code to place a listener on each square in the grid then?

Comment: It made no difference. The table itself does not have a class of tic tac toe, it's only the td's so I don't think that helped.

Comment: Ok.  I dont know what the class of your table is.  But replace .tictactoe with table, assuming you have no other tables on your page.   $('table td').

Comment: Ids need to be unique in a html-document. I guess you have more of the same ids? You'll need to use something different then

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you used the following instead:

```
$(this).attr('id') == "upright"
```